# MySQL SUM two columns then another column with the net amount

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi ive tried all the solution on stack over flow to no avail

i have 2 tables with a ID primary key, then date, and amount. there can be multiple dates of the same date in the table. the debits uses negative numbers in debits table

```
table "credits" 

id | date | amount
1   2020-01-01  10.00
2   2020-01-02  20.00
3   2020-01-03  30.00
4   2020-01-01  10.00
5   2020-01-02  10.00
6   2020-01-03  10.00

table "debits"

id  |  date | amount
55   2020-01-01  -5.00
56   2020-01-02  -5.00
57   2020-01-03  -5.00
58   2020-01-01  -5.00
59   2020-01-02  -5.00
60   2020-01-03  -5.00
```

I want to return a 3 column result like so, grouped by DATE with 4 fields, date, amount credits (for teh day) amount debits (for the day) and the amont total (for the day)

```
date | amount_credits | amount_debits | amount_total
2020-01-01    20    10    10
2020-01-02    30    10    20
2020-01-03    40    10    30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using `union all` and aggrgtion:

```
select date, sum(credit) as credits, abs(sum(debits)) as debits),
       sum(credits) + sum(debits) as net
from ((select c.date, c.amount as credit, 0 as debit
       from credits c
      ) union all
      (select c.date, 0, d.amount
       from debits d
      )
     ) cd
group by date;
```

I note that the sign of the debits amount changes, from the source table to the result set, which is why the outer query uses `abs()`.

In particular, using `union all` and `group by` ensures that all dates in the original data are in the result set -- even if the date in in only one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd group both tables on the date and then join the two:

```sql
SELECT c.date, amount_credits, amount_debits, amount_credits - amount_debits AS amount_total
FROM   (SELECT   date, SUM(amount) AS amount_credits
        FROM     credits
        GROUP BY date) c 
JOIN   (SELECT   date, -1 * SUM(amount) AS amount_debits
        FROM     debits
        GROUP BY date) d ON c.date = d.date
```